# Chaining completable futures based on conditions

Tags: java, asynchronous, exception, completable-future, conditional-execution

I am having a bunch of methods that return a CompletableFuture and I would like to chain in a specific way

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class SandboxFutures {

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> generateRandom(int min, int max) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            if (min >= max) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("max must be greater than min");
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            return r.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<String> printEvenOrOdd(int result) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            if (result % 2 == 0)
                return "Even";
            else
                return "Odd";
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> findFactorial(int evenNumber) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            if (evenNumber <= 0) {
                return 0;
            }

            return IntStream.rangeClosed(2, evenNumber).reduce(1, (x,y) -> x*y);
        });
    }

    public CompletableFuture<Integer> convertToNearestEvenInteger(int oddNumber) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           if (oddNumber <= 0) {
               return 2;
           }
           return oddNumber+1;
        });
    }

}
```

I am trying to combine them based on the following rules,

1. Generate a random number between 1 and 100
2. If the number is even print `Even`, if it is odd print `Odd`
3. If the number is even call the `findFactorial` with the random number
4. If the number is odd find the nearest even via `convertToNearestEvenInteger`

I am not too clear on how to do the conditional chaining and exception handling. Some examples or code snippets may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way `printEvenOrOdd` is written makes it more difficult than it needs to be. The problem is that it doesn't *print* the word "Even" or "Odd", it *returns* it, which means the original `result` is lost. The rest of the steps rely on having the actual number. To work around it, you could use call `printEvenOrOdd` and use `.thenApply(__ -> result)` to restore the original number afterwards. It would look like this:

```
System.out.println(
    generateRandom(1, 100)
        .thenCompose(result ->
            printEvenOrOdd(result)
                .thenAccept(System.out::println)
                .thenApply(__ -> result)
        )
        .thenCompose(result ->
            result % 2 == 0
                ? findFactorial(result)
                : convertToNearestEvenInteger(result)
        )
        .join()
);
```

A better solution would be to change the definition of `printEvenOrOdd` to something like:

```
public CompletableFuture<Integer> printEvenOrOdd(int result) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println(result % 2 == 0 ? "Even" : "Odd");
        return result;
    });
}
```

That would make it much easier to chain steps 3 and 4:

```
System.out.println(
    generateRandom(1, 100)
        .thenApply(this::printEvenOrOdd)
        .thenCompose(result ->
            result % 2 == 0
                ? findFactorial(result)
                : convertToNearestEvenInteger(result)
        )
        .join()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`thenCompose()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-):

```
CompletableFuture<Integer> n = generateRandom(1, 100)
        .thenCompose(i -> printEvenOrOdd(i)
                .thenCompose(s -> s.equals("Even")
                        ? findFactorial(i)
                        : convertToNearestEvenInteger(i)));
System.out.println(n.get());
```

However, when big even numbers are generated, your factorial method can't store anything bigger than `int`, so you need to update that.